# VB.NET Getting Value On Dynamic Control

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB and run into some problems.

I have created sub routine that will automatically add a control to a panelcontrol each time i click on the button, so it can create as many as i want.

Here is the code for the subroutine.

```
Private Sub CreateControl()

    'CREATE TEXTBOX ITEMNO
    Dim i_Itemno As Integer = TextEditItemno.Length
    ReDim Preserve TextEditItemno(i_Itemno)
    TextEditItemno(i_Itemno) = New TextEdit
    With TextEditItemno(i_Itemno)
        .Name = "Txtitemno" & i_Itemno.ToString()
        If TextEditItemno.Length < 2 Then
            .SetBounds(0, 0, 32, 20)
        Else
            .Left = TextEditItemno(i_Itemno - 1).Left
            .Top = TextEditItemno(i_Itemno - 1).Top + TextEditItemno(i_Itemno - 1).Height + 4
            .Size = TextEditItemno(i_Itemno - 1).Size
        End If
        .Tag = i_Itemno
    End With
    AddHandler TextEditItemno(i_Itemno).TextChanged, AddressOf TextEditItemno_TextChanged
    PanelControl5.Controls.Add(TextEditItemno(i_Itemno))


    'CREATE TEXTBOX PRICE
    Dim i_Price As Integer = TextEditPrice.Length
    ReDim Preserve TextEditPrice((i_Price))
    Dim PriceX As Int16 = LblHarga.Location.X
    TextEditPrice(i_Price) = New TextEdit
    With TextEditPrice(i_Price)
        .Name = "Txtprice" & i_Price.ToString()
        If TextEditSatuan.Length < 2 Then
            .SetBounds(PriceX, 0, 70, 20)
        Else
            .Left = TextEditPrice(i_Price - 1).Left
            .Top = TextEditPrice(i_Price - 1).Top + TextEditPrice(i_Price - 1).Height + 4
            .Size = TextEditPrice(i_Price - 1).Size
        End If
        .Tag = i_Price
    End With
    AddHandler TextEditPrice(i_Price).TextChanged, AddressOf TextEditPrice_TextChanged
    PanelControl5.Controls.Add(TextEditPrice(i_Price))


End Sub
```

And i call it in a button click.

```
Private Sub btnNew_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNew.Click
    CreateControl()
End Sub
```

Now what i am looking for is how to loop and get the value of those textboxes no matter how many textboxex i have create.

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To TextEditItemno.Length - 1
        ' code to get the value of each textbox
    Next
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code goes in to your loop and gets the value of each textbox based on `i`.

```
Dim Text as String = TextEditItemno(i).Text
```

You may also be better served by using a `List(of Textbox)` rather than an array of textboxes.  You don't need to worry about redimming the array, you can just do `MyListOfTextboxes.Add(TheNewTextBox)`. You can still retrieve the value of each textbox the same way as the array.

Comment: Nice, thank you so much. One additional question how to get the index of the focused textboxes? I mean i have created maybe lets say 10 textboxes and i set my cursor to textboxe no#3, so howw this can be done? Because sometime i need to update vaalue and recalculate it.

Comment: I would keep a `CurrentTextbox` variable around and set it equal to the `sender` variable from the `Focused` event attached to the textboxes.  You could then do `TextEditItemno.IndexOf(CurrentTextbox)`.  If my answer solves your original problem you should mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark next to it.